# How to iterate through a lists of lists and delete a certain element?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Say I have a list of lists such as

```
l1 = {{a, 2}, {a, 5}, {b, 3}, {b, 9}}
```

How would I iterate through the list and delete all the lists with the first element b so that i can get

```
l2 = {{a,2}, {a, 5}}
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. One way to do it `l1 // Select[FreeQ[First@#, b] &]`

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {{a, 2}, {a, 5}, {b, 3}, {b, 9}};
l2 = {{a, 2}, {a, 5}};
(*method 1*) DeleteCases[l1, {b, _}]
(*method 2*) Select[l1, First@#1 =!= b &];
(*method 3*) Select[l1, FreeQ[#, b] &];
(*method 4*) Pick[l1, #1 =!= b & @@@ l1];
(*method 5*) (l1 /. {b, _} -> Sequence[]);
(*method 6*) Reap[If[#[[1]] =!= b, Sow@#, Sequence[]] & /@ l1][[2, 1]];
SameQ @@ Out[-Range[6]]
```

> {{a, 2}, {a, 5}}
>
> True

And a more procedural way/actually using iterators, and "deleting" the "b"s instead of picking out the not-"b"s,

```
Block[
 {list = l1, i = 0},
 Do[
  If[l1[[k, 1]] === b, list = Delete[list, k - i]; i++], 
  {k, Length@l1}
 ];
 list
]
```

> {{a, 2}, {a, 5}}

Answer (score 3):

Another way.

```
l2 = l1 /. {b, _} -> Nothing
(* {{a, 2}, {a, 5}} *}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a, 2}, {a, 5}, {b, 3}, {b, 9}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3}

```
First @ SequenceSplit[list, {{b, _}}]
```

{{a, 2}, {a, 5}}

Or, via `Position`

```
p = Position[list, {b, _}]
```

{{3}, {4}}

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

{{a, 2}, {a, 5}}

```
MapAt[Nothing, p] @ list
```

{{a, 2}, {a, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {{a, 2}, {a, 5}, {b, 3}, {b, 9}};
l2 = {{a, 2}, {b, 3}, {a, 5}, {b, 9}};
```

Using `Position` and `Span`:

```
p = Flatten@Position[Sort[#], x_ /; FreeQ[x, b], 1, Heads -> False] &;

Sort[#][[Span @@ p@#]] &@l1

(*{{a, 2}, {a, 5}}*)

Sort[#][[Span @@ p@#]] &@l2

(*{{a, 2}, {a, 5}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAt`:

```
p = Position[#, x_ /; ! FreeQ[x, b], 1, Heads -> False] &;

ReplaceAt[l1, f_ :> Nothing, p@l1]

(*{{a, 2}, {a, 5}}*)

ReplaceAt[l2, f_ :> Nothing, p@l2]

(*{{a, 2}, {a, 5}}*)
```